# Better to run 4 SSD drives in RAID 0, or have 2 2xSSD RAID0?

Tags: ssd, raid-0

I have 4 SSD drives

- 2 identical old ones: Corsair SSD Extreme X32 2,5"  32GB - SATA2, read/write 220MB/135MB
- 2 identical new ones: Corsair CSSD-F40GB2-A Force Series 40GB, read/write 280MB/270MB

At the moment I have the 2 new ones as RAID0 and have installed my OS on that RAID0 setup. I also have the 2 old ones as RAID0 and was thinking I could use that drive as a temporary storage partition for current work, and caching for illustrator, lightroom, photoshop, picasa and some other software.

I'm wondering whether I'd just be better off putting all 4 drives into one big RAID0 array. I assume everything drops to the lowest common denominator, but potentially having 4xSSD's in a RAID0 running at the lower speed would still be more effective than 2xSSDs in RAID0 at a higher speed.

I believe another downside to running all 4xSSDs in a single RAID0 array is that I'd also lose storage space and would have a RAID0 array of 4x32GB.

Any advice/thoughts appreciated :)

*PS. I won't be relying on these drives for any permanent data storage, that will fall to 2x2TB drives in RAID1.*

Comment: http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/02/sql-on-ssds-hot-crazy-love/

Comment: Interesting watching. I am fully aware that if any of my RAID0 drives fails that's me kaput, and I suppose I'd increase that risk to 4x by doing a RAID0 array across the 4 drives, but I'm not really concerned about drive failure in my RAID0 array due to it only being OS and all data will be securely stored on my magnetic RAID1.

Comment: I was posting that video due to the insights into relation between SSD capacity and speed.

Comment: It's pretty interesting, and I definitely learnt from it. I had not realised the base construction of SSDs and how write speed can increase with increased capacity. Quite cool thanks :)